# Eventcallback string not working in blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have a generic text controller, please see my code below. I'm getting if (ValueChanged.HasDelegate) always false.  what could be the issue that HasDelegate getting always false ? I'm expecting true value. Thanks!

```
 <RadzenTextBox Disabled="@(IsSaving || Disabled)" 
                       Style="width: 100%" 
                       @bind-Value=@Value 
                       Change="@(OnChange)" />

private async Task OnChange(string selectedValue)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PropertyName) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedValue))
                return;

            IsSaving = true;
            await DealRepository.UpdateSingleField(DealId, PropertyName, selectedValue);            
            IsSaving = false;

            if (ValueChanged.HasDelegate)
                await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(selectedValue);          
        }


[Parameter] public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you share the code that uses this component? Unless someone is listening to ValueChanged, it will not have delegates

Comment: if (ValueChanged.HasDelegate)
                await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(selectedValue);  this condition is always false.

Comment: You don't need to check for delegates. Remove the if condition and simply call InvokeAsync

Comment: ValueChanged is yours and you have to create a method (delegate) for them. in your last line of code, you define event, and you have to declare a method too. like: protected void ValueChanged(string value) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while calling generic text controller I have changed Value  to @bind-Value and my issue is resolved.

```
    <RowTextBox Disabled="true" Title="Address" @bind-Value="@val" PropertyName="Test" DealId="@Id"></RowTextBox>
```